# parsing a jquery/javascript object into an array or useable data

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, javascript-objects

When  I perform a `$.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost.com", function(data) {
  console.log(data)
  console.log(data.posts);
});
```

This is what I get - how do I get the posts array into variables or a useable format? I have tried to

```
console.log(data.posts)
```

with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Use dot notation. `data.posts.whateverYouWant`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... You are just printing the array - I can't see that you are assigning anything to a variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.posts` *is* what you want. It is an object that contains an array named `posts`. To get it, use

```
var posts = data.posts.posts;
```

Comment: boom...that simple var posts = data.posts[0].author.name;